# how to get data from a json file when testing with mocha

Tags: node.js, json, mocha.js, chai, testcase

**this is my test case code**

```
describe('States Get', () => {
    
        describe('/post /states', () => {
            it('it should get states Json Data', () => {
                let obj = {
                    "Country_Code":""
                }
                chai.request(app)
                    .post('/api/states/statesjson')
                    .set('Accept', 'application/json')               
                    .send(obj)
                    .end((err, res) => {
    
                        res.should.have.status(200);
                        res.body.should.be.an('object');
                        res.body.should.have.property('message').eql('success');
                        res.body.should.have.property('response');
                        done();
                 });
             });
        });
    });
```

**how to get the data from a json file ???**
below is my method to get data i want to test on that

```
const GetStatesData = (request, response) => {
    const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(statespath, "utf-8");
    let getdata = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    response.json(utill.responseSuccessJSON(200, "success", result));
}
```

**getting few errors like these... i am getting result in actual, how to remove all these**

```
throw err;
    ^
AssertionError: expected [ Array(2) ] to have property 'x-access-token'
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  showDiff: false,
  actual: [
    {  },
    {  }
  ],
  expected: undefined
```

Comment: If I've understood correctly you can try [mock-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs) package. If this cna solve you issue I can explain better in an answer.

Comment: is there any thing else some alternatives

Comment: hi J.F can u explain me mock-fs package usage